# Remove zero's columns in a xtable [R]

Tags: r, printing, xtable

I would appreciate your help to solve my issue.
I am making a Delta Analysis of customer reputation 13 vs 14 to detect the change levels in reputation for each customer.
To improve the redability, I need to remove the zeros's columns from my table generated with the showed code.
I attached the result HTML.

```
"Reputation_Cutomer13" and ...14: categorical variables, [1,5]
"CHR1413": categorical variable, [-5,5]

library(etable)
RCH1314Complete<-tabular.ade(x_vars="Reputation_Cutomer13",
                 rows=c("Reputation_Cutomer13"), rnames=c("Reputation_Cutomer13"),
                 cols=c("Reputation_Cutomer14", "CHR1413"), cnames=c("Reputation_Cutomer14", "CHR1413"), data= business_Delta1, FUN=n_cell)

multi_table <-print (xtable(RCH1314Complete, caption="Reputation 13 vs (Reputation 14 and [change reputation])"), include.rownames=F, include.colnames=F,
                     caption.placement="top", type = "html", file="RCH1314Complete.html")
```

```html
<!-- html table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package -->
<!-- Mon Oct 19 13:09:45 2015 -->
<table border=1>
<caption align="top"> Reputation 13 vs (Reputation 14 and [change reputation]) </caption>
  <tr> <td>  </td> <td> Reputation_Cutomer13 </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td> Reputation_Cutomer14 </td> <td>  </td> <td> 0 </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td> 1 </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td> 2 </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td> 3 </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td> 4 </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td> 5 </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> <td>  </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td> CHR1413 </td> <td>  </td> <td> -5 </td> <td> -4 </td> <td> -3 </td> <td> -2 </td> <td> -1 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 1 </td> <td> 2 </td> <td> 3 </td> <td> 4 </td> <td> 5 </td> <td> -5 </td> <td> -4 </td> <td> -3 </td> <td> -2 </td> <td> -1 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 1 </td> <td> 2 </td> <td> 3 </td> <td> 4 </td> <td> 5 </td> <td> -5 </td> <td> -4 </td> <td> -3 </td> <td> -2 </td> <td> -1 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 1 </td> <td> 2 </td> <td> 3 </td> <td> 4 </td> <td> 5 </td> <td> -5 </td> <td> -4 </td> <td> -3 </td> <td> -2 </td> <td> -1 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 1 </td> <td> 2 </td> <td> 3 </td> <td> 4 </td> <td> 5 </td> <td> -5 </td> <td> -4 </td> <td> -3 </td> <td> -2 </td> <td> -1 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 1 </td> <td> 2 </td> <td> 3 </td> <td> 4 </td> <td> 5 </td> <td> -5 </td> <td> -4 </td> <td> -3 </td> <td> -2 </td> <td> -1 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 1 </td> <td> 2 </td> <td> 3 </td> <td> 4 </td> <td> 5 </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>  </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 317 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 1087 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 2971 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 3941 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 2272 </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>  </td> <td> 1 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 321 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 61 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 157 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 207 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 147 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 20 </td> <td> 0 </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>  </td> <td> 2 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 971 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 204 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 586 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 953 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 693 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 91 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>  </td> <td> 3 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 2574 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 336 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 1176 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 3048 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 3132 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 621 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>  </td> <td> 4 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 2345 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 279 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 934 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 3726 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 6507 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 2914 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>  </td> <td> 5 </td> <td> 413 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 47 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 148 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 926 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 3051 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 6568 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> <td> 0 </td> </tr>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is probably easier done by stripping the zeros before you call `xtable`.

```
library(magrittr)
mtcars_noZero <- lapply(mtcars,
       function(x){ x[x == 0] <- ""; x}) %>%
  as.data.frame(, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

A couple more options to consider

You can use the `sanitize.text.function`, but this only works on character vectors, so you'll need to change every column in your table to a character before it will work, and I'm not sure that gains you much over my previous answer.

```
remove_zero <- function(x) gsub("0", "", x)

mtcars <- as.data.frame(lapply(mtcars, as.character),
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

print(xtable(mtcars,
             caption="Reputation 13 vs (Reputation 14 and [change reputation])"),
      sanitize.text.function = remove_zero,
      include.rownames=F, include.colnames=F,
      caption.placement="top", type = "html")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunatly for me it does not work because the zeros in my table are generated during the process, I mean:
If I have 100 customers on Reputation 13 =1. On 2014 they can change reputation from -1 to 5 with any distribution....plus the new customers on 2014

Comment: I'm having a hard time envisioning why this wouldn't work.  You should put your final data frame through the `lapply` statement immediately before pushing it to `print.xtable(xtable(...), ...)` it should work just fine.  But I've given another option using the `sanitize.text.function` argument.  Either way, you've got to do some preprocessing before you go to `xtable`, and I don't think that can be avoided.

Comment: thanks for your help. I run the first option but I lost the structure of the table and I can not revise the result.  
How can I recover the initial structure?.

Comment: What's the class of your table?  Is it `data.frame`? `tbl_df`? `data.table`?  something different?

Comment: class(RCH1314Complete)
[1] "matrix"

Comment: That makes a difference. I  assumed a data frame. Try using `RCH1314Complete[RCH1314Complete == 0] <- ""`.  That should retain the matrix structure and pass to `xtable` nicely.

Comment: OK. Right now the zeros columns are empty, how can I hiding or removing them before print?